# View contacts but not activities

Tags: permissions

I'm a bit stumped on permissions.  I'm trying to create a user role that can

- See and edit any user
- See and edit custom fields for the user
- NOT see or edit activities for any user
- NOT see any financial information for any user

I tried this combination of settings:

- CiviCRM: view all contacts : CHECKED
- CiviCRM: view all activities : NOT CHECKED
- CiviCRM: Delete activities : NOT CHECKED
- CiviCRM: access CiviCRM backend and API : CHECKED
- CiviCRM: access Contact Dashboard : CHECKED

This arrangement seems to allow the user to see all contacts but also all activities on all contacts.

If I remove "CiviCRM: view all contacts" then the user can see no contacts at all, and no activities.

I don't really understand why "view all contacts" gives access to see activities when the activity permissions are turned off.  That seems counterintuitive.

And I can't find a combination of permissions that allows a user to see/edit all users, but not see/edit any activities.

Suggestions?

(CiviCRM 5.8.2 on Drupal 7.  I'm aware a security update is needed to CiviCRM.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess [Activity type ACL](https://github.com/JMAConsulting/biz.jmaconsulting.activitytypeacl) extension will do your job. This extension provides additional permission for each activity type. By default its set to false for all activity type.

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: Thank you.  That worked.